# Calculating the current member balance based on transactional data

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a MySQL table of financial transactions.

The table is like so:

```
+----+-----------+--------+--------+---------+---------+
| id | member_id | status | amount | opening | closing |
+----+-----------+--------+--------+---------+---------+
| 1  | 2         | 1      | 1000   | 0       | 1000    |
| 2  | 2         | 2      | 100    | 1000    | 1000    |
| 3  | 2         | 1      | -20    | 1000    | 980     |
| 4  | 2         | 1      | 10     | 980     | 990     |
+----+-----------+--------+--------+---------+---------+
```

Currently the opening and closing fields are empty. Status 1 is committed, and 2 is uncommitted.

Can some one please tell me how I would write a query to scan the entire table and update all the opening and closing balances?

There is almost 1,000,000 records in this table so it would be nice if the query was quite optimized. Also this is not going to be needed for real time mission critical data. It would only be the current estimation of the members balance.

Comment: What do you want to update them with? Random values?

Comment: The opening can closing balance for that transaction. You would think that was obvious.

Comment: not at all - the opening balance is a sum of all transactions before the current one according to a certain attribute and closing balance is after the current transaction. We can assume that the attribute is member_id and that we should only consider the transactions with status 1 and that before is determined by id < current.id, but these are assumptions.

Comment: Also which version of mysql? And is update/insert performance as important as select? You mention you want to query few hundreds several times a second. Can you give similar figures for inserts (and updates and deletes), if it is relevant?

Comment: Look at my solution below - it does exactly what you asked for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an oversight in ajreal's solution - it doesn't reset the balance variables for different member ids. This version fixes that.

This works (I tested it):

```
set @clo:=0, @opn:=0, @mem:=0; 
update member_txns 
set
  opening=if(status=1, @opn:=if(@mem=(@mem:=member_id), @clo, 0), @clo), 
  closing=if(status=1, @clo:=@opn+amount, @clo) 
order by member_id, id;
```

Answer (score 2):

**You really dont want to implement it in this way.** You have no idee the world of hurt you will find yourself in when you need to back date a transaction. 1m records arent that many, so indexing should be sufficiant...

Comment: but what about 1,000,000 records with a join onto the member table (of 30,000 records)

Comment: Oh and transactions are never back dated. If any corrections need to be made then a new transaction is made to accomplish this.

Comment: Still, this can be handle efficiently without having to store calculated fileds. Correct indexing, and database design should be enough...

Comment: Alright can you help me how to write a efficient query to get all members and there current balance?

Comment: It takes about 13 seconds to query as you suggested

Comment: as i said in my response, what happens when a Status changes from 2 to 1, does all the data following it need to update the opening and closing values accordingly? in this case you are effectively 'back dating records' regardless of when the record was originally written as status 2.

Comment: @Petah Nov 20 at 6:37: The join shouldn't really affect this, the join is still going to result in at most 1M records it and the calculation backwards for the running total should not be looking at the members table at all (only the transactions table)

Answer (score 0):

1. Storing the balance is denormalisation here and not required
2. If you really want to store the balance, it should be in the Members table

A simple `SELECT member_id, SUM(amount) as Balance GROUP BY member_id` will give you the result. If you really have have a performance issue, you could always transpose a [nice trick by Allen Browne](http://allenbrowne.com/AppInventory.html) to you situation.

Comment: I know what denormalisation is. And why do you say it is not required? My server is not that fast, and with 30,000+ users it can get hit quite hard at times. The purpose of this is denormalisation for optimisation. Yes that `SELECT` would work with a few `WHERE` clauses added in, but it runs slow, especially under load.

Comment: Just to clarify. I need to run this balance query on up to 100 members (in a `JOIN` with a `LIMIT`) up to a few time per second.

Comment: ok for denormalisation then. What about point 2 and the provided link ?

Comment: The link provided goes on about how this value is mission critical and must be updated at every insert, update and delete. This is not the case for me, I'm happy for the values not to be 100% accurate some times. These are only used as indicative values. Also he provides a visual basic script (and a poorly commented one at that). I didn't find it very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt at analysis of the situation

First I have created 1M records using small python script

```
import csv
import random
ofile = open('sample.csv', "wb")
writer = csv.writer(ofile)
for i in xrange(1000000):
    row = [ i, i/(5+random.randint(0,10)), 1+random.randint(0,10)/10, random.randint(10, 200)*10, 0 ]   
    writer.writerow(row)
ofile.close()
```

then create table transactions

```
CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `member_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `opening` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

(from which I dropped closing balance, that one is denormalization that makes no sense)

Then load the data with

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'sample.csv' INTO TABLE transactions FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

However my first problem is establishing bad performance, the following query, without any indexes added runs in 0.10 sec

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE member_id, SUM(amount) 
FROM transactions 
WHERE member_id between 500 and 1000 AND status = 1 
GROUP BY member_id;
```

Then I tried to join on members table, which I created from existing transaction data but the query

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE member_id, name, SUM(amount) 
FROM transactions JOIN members ON transactions.member_id = members.id 
WHERE member_id between 500 and 1000 AND status = 1 
GROUP BY member_id;
```

run in 0.17 sec

So, I was not able to replicate the problem. So, I propose the above queries as solutions or alternatively request more information to try to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution requires a program - I'll show it via a stored procedure.

SQL is particularly bad at doing queries that rely on the order of rows in a table based on column(s) where the values are unknown - like your id column. The only way to tackle such cases is with some kind of executable code that scans through the data.

Although you haven't stated it, I'll assume the logic is:

1. Process rows ordered by member and id
2. Ignore rows where status = 2
3. Set opening to 0 if it's the first row found for a member
4. Update the closing to be the opening plus the amount

Note that there is one obvious issue here: What happens if a status changes (either from 2 to 1 or 1 to 2)? It will require a recalculation of that member's transactions from that point on

Here's the stored procedure that does this:

```
drop procedure if exists calculate_balances;
delimiter ~
create procedure calculate_balances()
comment 'calculates running balances'
begin
declare _id int;
declare _member_id int;
declare _amount int;
declare _balance int;
declare _current_member_id int default 0;
declare _done int default 0;

declare _cursor cursor for
select id, member_id, case when status = 1 then amount else 0 end
from member_txns
order by member_id, id;

declare continue handler for not found set _done = 1;

open _cursor;

repeat
  fetch _cursor into _id, _member_id, _amount;

  if not _done then
    if _current_member_id != _member_id then
      set _balance = 0;
      set _current_member_id = _member_id;
    end if;

    update member_txns set opening = _balance, closing = _balance + _amount where id = _id;

    set _balance = _balance + _amount;
  end if;
until _done end repeat;

end;~
delimiter ;
```

Note that the treatment of status is handled in the query.

Here's the code to test:

```
create table member_txns ( 
id int,
member_id int,
status int,
amount int,
opening int,
closing int
);

insert into member_txns (id, member_id, status, amount) values 
(1,2,1,1000),
(2,2,2,100),
(3,2,1,-20),
(4,2,1,10),
(5,3,1,-20),
(6,3,1,100);

call calculate_balances();

select * from member_txns;
```

Executing these commands will show the stored procedure produces the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Why not a materialized view created from stored procedures? It would separate the logic between data and calculated values. It would also give the fastest possible queries.

Comment: Why not? The reasons for not using a materialized view created from stored procedures are a) it isn't scalable (1M rows) b) the data is static, so calculating it once makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Bohemian: I don't think you really have a handle on what they are.

Answer (score 0):

You do not state what happens when a Status changes from 2 to 1, does all the data following it need to update the opening and closing values accordingly? if not then your system has serious problems. if so then you will be needing to recalculate all this data a whole lot of times, is this the reason why you're asking this question in the first place?

Firstly, there is no reason to store both Opening and Closing values for all records,
Closing = Opening + (CASE WHEN Status = 1 THEN Amount Else 0 END), this will half the calculations you need.

Following on from this, perhaps you would be better off to only store every 10, 20, 50 or 100+ records as key points. Thus you are making a summary for just the bracket of 100 ID values which total up to 73020. If you really want you could change this to also then include the total running total of all previous values at a summarized level.

Usually Financial systems only store Opening and Closing values at a month by month period basis and within that month they are recalculated. Think about how often your users will actually need this data compared to the overcomplexity in having to constantly update it when a status '2' becomes a status '1'

I would suggest you store periodic values instead such as:

```
+--------+--------+---------+-------+
| Period | Member | Opening | Total |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+
| 1      | 1      | 0       | 50    |
| 2      | 1      | 50      | 1000  |
| 2      | 2      | 0       | 100   |
| 3      | 1      | 1050    | 0     |
| 3      | 2      | 50      | 600   |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+
```

And so on, this is a much better data schema and it's considerably easier to maintain.

To update these values you just determine the period you need to update and then recalculate the total for that period, you then just update all subsequent Opening values. Even with 30,000 different members you will take 4 years for this 'period table' to reach 1million records (provided you use monthly periods), in that time I would expect you to have considerably more transactions than that (of the order of 10-50 times more), thus doing this implementation results in 10-50 times reduction in workload for a very minimal impact to the end users performance.